# Use link url upon click in PHP

Tags: php, vb.net

I want to use the URL of the link that was clicked in a **VB.net** program. How can I take the url from my browser url bar and use it in my **PHP** program?

**Example:**

**VB.net** - click link then open using a web browser

```
url: www.something.com/id=^%$#@&var2=13lfhd3f4gt
```

**PHP** - put the link in a variable or something so that I can use explode command to get the `id` and `var2` from the URL itself

I need those variables to output a certain value from my database.

Comment: [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has the answer that you are looking for, for getting the url in PHP:
[Get the full URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/php-get-the-full-url)

Though for getting `id` and `var2`, it would be simpler to just use the `$_GET` variable in php.  Then you don't have to explode the url and process it.  Just change the '/' after 'com' to a ? like:
 www.something.com?id=^%$#@&var2=13lfhd3f4gt

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do it?

Comment: For using the $_GET variable, you just go $id = $_GET['id'] and $var2 = $_GET['var2'].  You will want to make sure that the values are not null before you use them but that would make your life easier. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: So I'll use the program will look like. Please tell me if I'm wrong:

$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$leave_id = $_GET['id'];
if(!empty($leave_id){
 //Run the program
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using eg. `$_SERVER` global variable. Please refer to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)